# is it possible to build a cardano multicurrency dApp wallet?

Tags: wallet, decentralized-applications

Will there be a cardano dapp built for multicurrency wallet, like Exodus and Guarda, that's desktop based, but built on cardano?

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding Exodus and Guarda are not dapps, which makes your question tricky to answer. I'm going to try and answer some questions that may be related to what you are asking and hope it helps.

First, Cardano is available on many of these multicurrency wallets so if your question related to have ADA or and Cardano tokens added to these wallets then it already is in place. ADA is supported on Exodus for example and I assume they will integrate support for other Cardano-based tokens once they are released.

Next, if your question relates to the dapp support that Exodus has, in particular compound, then I think this is certainly possible down the line. I can certainly see Exodus integrating support for a Cardano-based DeFi dapp given it has enough community support and usage.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking more of a blockchain multicurrency wallet. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a wallet that can hold multiple tokens besides ADA?

If so, both Yoroi and Daedalus already support that.

Comment: Yes, like can I send bitcoin, litecoin, ethereum, polygon, tezos on daedalus or yoroi wallets?

Comment: No, for that you need a wallet like Exodus.